# why is my call to a mock api not parsing the data as expected?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to debug and find a reason why this isn't working and how to get it to work.

MainActivity.kt

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ...

    fetchJson()
}
```

so this just calls my function `fetchJson`

this is the function:

```
fun fetchJson() {
    println("Attempting to Fetch JSON")

    val url = "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5ed340ab340000650001f28c"

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: okhttp3.Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: okhttp3.Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Failed to execute request")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: okhttp3.Call, response: okhttp3.Response) {
            val body = response?.body?.string()
            println(body)
            println("success")
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body, note::class.java)

           /* runOnUiThread {
                recycler_view.adapter = MainAdapter(homeFeed)
            }*/
        }

    })
```

the idea behind this is that you take JSON data and fit it into adapter classes and display them in a card view.

my problem isn't with the adapters or the card view but the rest API. It doesn't want to work with my mock rest API, but it will work with other rest API's. I'm not sure why though?

I've tried to add a network security exception, I've had to remove my adapter class just to get it to say success. I still can't find the JSON body in the console when I get the onresponse call, and because I don't get errors in the debug console I don't know what is going on.

I have no clue what isn't working here. Is it GSON converters?, the rest API, my code? is a problem with my emulator?...etc?

the classes the body should print to the console:

```
class note(val noteis: List<Mlist>)

class Mlist(val text1: String, val text2: String, val text3: String)
```

Comment: `and because I don't get error's in the debug console` well, your `onFailure` method isn't particularly useful here. printing that the request failed won't help you debug, instead you should be printing the stacktrace of the exception. that `onFailure` is not just for failing to make a request, but for a request failing, which isn't the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems I can see:

1. No stacktrace in `onFailure` method. Let's add it:

```
println("Failed to execute request, $e")
```

Running this now returns 
`PKIX path building failed: (...) unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
This fails because Java does not trust the certificate from `www.mocky.io`. You can add it or ignore it by changing the configuration of `OkHttpClient`, but for now let's simply change the url from `https://` to `http://`.

With that change you should be getting response body printed out, if not your error is beyond provided code.

2. Response class does not match the json data.

JSON data from the link looks like this:

```
{
    "Mlist": {
        "text1": "text1a",
        "text2": "text2a",
        "text3": "text3a"
    }
}
```

So it is not a list of `Mlist` objects, but a single object in a field named `Mlist`.
To match this we can:

a) change the name of the field in the `note` class

```
class note(val Mlist: Mlist)
```

b) use `@SerializedName` annotation

```
    @SerializedName("Mlist")
    val notes: Mlist
```

Btw. you can change `note` and `Mlist` to `data class` to be able to see its content with `print*` methods.

Comment: thank you for the tip on the stack trace. I was able to find out why It wouldn't even show up in the debug. thank you.